# Extract URL from text with multiple URLs using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a string with a text and several URLs. How can I extract one specific URL (of a spoecific domain) with sed?
For example, I have this:

```
Text foo bar Text foo bar <br /><br /> http://www.this.file <br />http://another.file <br />http://mine.com/this.html <br />http://myURL.net/files/IWANTthis <br />http://www.google.com/thisnot
```

and `sed` shall return this:
 `http://myURL.net/files/IWANTthis`

Comment: Don't you do this with `grep`?

Comment: If you know how, yes please!

Comment: It's easy dude, do some trial/error work starting with something like `| sed s/<br \/>/<br \/>\n/g | grep "myURL\.net"`

Comment: The exact works depend on your complete mileage. If you are moving to GNU/Linux, start by reading Eric S. Raymond's [The Art of Unix Programming](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/).

Answer (score 11):

There could be some trouble with sed on special cases. As has been suggested in many places [(e.g.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) - not to use regexps but a html parser engine. One such easily available parser is contained in the text only browser lynx (available on any linux). Then you just extract the urls you want with grep.

```
lynx -dump -listonly myhtmlfile.html | grep IWANTthis | sort -u
```

However this will not work on mangled html files (cannot be parsed properly) or text snippets with links. Another simple way is to chain. If you have a text snippet like yours in a text file called st3.txt you can do as follows:

```
grep http ./st3.txt | sed 's/http/\nhttp/g' | grep ^http | sed 's/\(^http[^ <]*\)\(.*\)/\1/g' | grep IWANTthis | sort -u
```

Explanation:

```
grep http ./st3.txt      => will catch lines with http from text file
sed 's/http/\nhttp/g'    => will insert newline before each http
grep ^http               => will take only lines starting with http
sed 's/\(^http[^ <]*\)\(.*\)/\1/g'   
                         => will preserve string from ^http until first space or <
grep IWANTthis           => will take only urls containing your text of interest
sort -u                  => will sort and remove duplicates from your list
```

Comment: Nice! You explained very well.

Comment: I use `lynx` as well, I find it useful but I've found `sed` actually rips more urls by itself since `sed` doesn't care about formatting and keeping up with the HTML standards.

Comment: Yes, `sed` just processes text, does not parse at all. For this reason - to minimise (but I cannot exclude them totally) such problems I first extract lines with http in them, make more lines by chopping _before_ each http then match those new lines until first space or angle bracket - since hyperlink cannot contain those and then hopefully I only have list of links, from which I extract those with text of interest. Line breaks _inside_ URLS would break this of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` with an extended [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (regex) for this:

```
grep -Eo '([-+.[:alnum:]]+://)?([-[:alnum:]]+.)*myURL.net(:[[:digit:]]+)?(/[[:graph:]]*)?' <<< '<input_string>'
```

Explanation of each part of the command and the regex:

- `grep -Eo`: We call `grep` with two options.

  - `-E`: Enable [POSIX extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) regexes.
  - `-o`: Print only the matched parts of each line (without this option, `grep` defaults to printing entire lines that contain matching parts).
- `'([-+.[:alnum:]]+://)?([-[:alnum:]]+.)*myURL.net(:[[:digit:]]+)?(/[[:graph:]]*)?'`: This regex is probably a bit fancier than what you need, so you should simplify or remove parts that are needlessly complex for your purposes. (The complexity is the result of an attempt to give a general solution.)

  - `([-+.[:alnum:]]+://)?`: This matches the [scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) of the URL. The `?` at the end specifies that this matches either once or not at all (so that `myURL.net` is matched even if no scheme is prepended). We include the slightly unusual characters `-+.` because [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1) specifies that "[s]cheme names consist of a sequence of characters beginning with a letter and followed by any combination of letters, digits, **plus ('+'), period ('.'), or hyphen ('-')**" (emphasis mine). If you are sure that `http://` will always appear in front of `myURL.net`, then you can replace this part of the regex with the simple `http://`.
  - `([-[:alnum:]]+.)*`: This matches [subdomains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain). The `*` at the end specifies that this matches zero or more times (so that subdomains like `a.b.` in `a.b.myURL.net` are matched). We include the hyphen (`-`) because [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-2.3.1) specifies that "[subdomain labels] must start with a letter, end with a letter or digit, and have as interior characters only letters, digits, and **hyphen**" (emphasis mine). If you are sure that you don't need to match subdomains, then you can remove this part of the regex.
  - `myURL.net`: This is a straightforward match for the literal string `myURL.net`.
  - `(:[[:digit:]]+)?`: This matches any [port designation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.3) if it is included in the URL.
  - `(/[[:graph:]]*)?`: This matches the rest of the URL. `[:graph:]` matches any visible character.
- `<<< '<input_string>'`: We feed `grep` (which accepts a file) our input string using a [here string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings). (`echo '<input_string>' |` is the common alternative.)

Example:

```
$ grep -Eo '([-+.[:alnum:]]+://)?([-[:alnum:]]+.)*myURL.net(:[[:digit:]]+)?(/[[:graph:]]*)?' <<< 'Text foo bar Text foo bar <br /><br /> http://www.this.file <br />http://another.file <br />http://mine.com/this.html <br />http://myURL.net/files/IWANTthis <br />http://www.google.com/thisnot'
http://myURL.net/files/IWANTthis
```

Again, the regex I gave above is probably overly complicated for what you need it to do. You should modify it to suit your purposes. Something as simple as the following could work:

```
grep -Eo 'http://myURL.net(/[[:graph:]]*)?' <<< '<input_string>'
```

Comment: It's really a bad idea to use regexp against XML (or HTML if you wish). See above answer why.

Answer (score 0):

You could use: `sed 's/<br\ *\/>/\n/g' html_file | grep myURL.net`

Output: `http://myURL.net/files/IWANTthis`

Basically I'm replacing all the `<br />` with a newline character and grabbing the relevant line with grep.

This does not account for all possible (html allowed) variations of the `<br>` tag, but it handles the ones in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the file for all urls with `sed` and then `grep` for your match. 
 
`sed "s/http/\nhttp/g" your.html | sed -n "s#\(.*\)\(http.*//[a-Z0-9./-]*[^a-Z/]\)\(.*\)#\2#p;" | grep IWANTthis`

In the first pass `sed` replaces all the http with a prepended newline to make things easier for `sed` on the second pass where `sed` rips the urls. This regex generally works for me but you may need to adjust it to suit your needs.

Note: You could do this in one pass but it will get complicated with cryptic potentially hard to maintain seldom used `sed` commands.